# Is it possible to use split() to partition a string of numbers?

Tags: python, split

I have a string of numbers:

```
str = "4284902384902384093284" 

output = []
```

And I want to partition `str` into strings of 3 digits and store it in `output`.

Is there anyway I can do this using `split()`?

I have done it using `two for loops` and also by `slicing`.

My issue with `split()` is that you need to tell Python what to split by, but since `str` is just a long list of numbers (with nothing, not even a space between numbers) I'm not sure how to apply `split()`;
i.e.

```
str.split(" ")
```

doesn't work and neither does `str.split("")`. My thinking is to throw it into an array `str = [str]`, but then I can't quite using split().

```
So for the above input, I would like it to produce: 

output = ["428","490","238",....]
```

Comment: On what basis do you split the string, meaning should the length of splited string should be same, or split on specific number

Comment: Not in a reasonable way.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. Sujay, let me give an example in case you do know a way!

Comment: You can use `re.split` and then split on the regex of any three characters, but I don't see a reason to use that over just using slices.

Comment: Split is meant to work on a delimiter.  You want to work on fixed length chunks. To me slicing is the obvious solution for the result you want. Why do you want to use split() specifically ?

Comment: The length of your string is not a multiple of 3...

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with `split`, but you can use a list expression with slicing.

```
output = [string[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)]
```

For your sample string, it produces:

```
['428', '490', '238', '490', '238', '409', '328', '4']
```

As others mentioned, you can also use regular expressions. Here's one way:

```
re.findall(r"\d{1,3}", string)
```

which produces the same result.

Also, it's bad form to name your string `str` as that's the name of the built-in string class.

Comment: Sorry poor choice of words. I didn't mean to suggest there was only one way to do it.